# Why does iTunes ask me to update my carrier settings?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

and then tell me that it has failed ...

Should I just ignore this as my phone is working fine?

My internet connection is fine.

[image]

Comment: What version of macOS and iOS are you using?  Does this happen when you connect your iPhone to your Mac?

Comment: Can you update the carrier settings on the iPhone? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201270

Comment: It happens when I connect my iPhone to my macBook Air via iTunes.  macOS - Mojave for Air and iOS 12.3.  My phone just told me I need to update again this time I'm not plugged in to my Air.